# Joomla Custom error page doesn't work well

Tags: php, joomla, custom-error-pages

For a long time I'm trying to enable custom 404 page for my joomla 2.5 website, because default red error page was not an option.

I enabled it, however, it shows only if user enters site.com/wrong_page and if users enter url of the following structure site.com/wrong_page/wrong_page it doesn't show anything, just blank empty page.

So, If user goes to a page "Goods" and then goes to unexisting item site.com/goods/wrong_itemid it wouldn't show custom error, it shows nothing, but if user opens site.com/wrong_link he will see custom error page.

Please, help me to sort this out.

I used the following in error.php:

```
switch ($this->error->code) {
   case '404':
      header('location: /404-page');
      break;
   case '500':
      include('500.php');
      break;
   case '403':
      include('403.php');
      break;
   default:
      header('location: /404-page');
    }
```

Comment: Show us some of you coding snippets

Comment: I added some code that I used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in Joomla 2.5

- create your custom '404' Article
- create a new unpublished menu item which links to this new 404 Article and 'apply' your changes. Copy the URL for this page (index.php?optio...)
- in your Joomla installation, copy the error.php file from the templates/system directory to your template directory.
- Edit the error.php file and add the following code immediately under the 'restricted access' line:

  if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
  header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=xx');
  exit;
  }

UPDATE
The above technique is intended as an easy way to make a custom page. You can use the built-in Joomla text editor and the page will match your site styling. @Flimm has correctly pointed out below that the page will no longer give a 404 HTTP header. If you are concerned about this, another option is:
- in your Joomla installation, copy the error.php file from the templates/system directory to your template directory.

- Open the copy of error.php in your template directory with any text editor and edit the HTML within the `<body>` tag however you like.

Good luck!

Comment: I feel like a fool, because, I think I tried it, but it didn't work last time)) But now that works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @user1584043, I'm pleased this got you unstuck!

Comment: @Flimm , thanks for pointing this out, I've updated my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it using *htaccess*.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /page500.php
```

Hope it helps..